# How to escape string and JSON.stringify

Tags: node.js, json, oracle, escaping, stringify

I'm trying to serve API with ***nodeJS***, and database use ***oracle***. I've an object like this that I got from `req.body.detail`:

```
{ 
    title: "How to Have", 
    content: "<ol><li><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</b></li></ol>"
}
```

then I do

```
const data = JSON.stringify(req.body.detail);
```

but the inserted data in table become doesn't has *escape string*, it become likes:

```
{"title":"How to Have","content":"<ol><li><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</b></li></ol>}
```

How do I can escape string to whole object and result become like this:

```
{"title":"How to Have","content":"<ol><li><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<\/b><\/li><\/ol>}
```

My column in table has datatype `clob`.

Comment: You do not need to escape the forward slashes in the string. I'm curious, why did you think you needed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To escape these `/` characters with `\`, use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
const escapedString = inputString.replace(/\//g, '\\/')
```

The first parameter is a regex.  Its `g` qualifier means match all instances, not just the first.   `\/` means match the `/` character, which must be replaced in a regex, because ....

regexes themselves start and end with `/`.  Hence `/\//g` .

And the replacement string literal is `\\/` because you must escape `\` to put it into a string literal:  `\\/` written in your program gets you the value `\/`.

But Oracle doesn't require you to escape these characters before you jam them into a clob. So that must be a requirement from the software that will read that clob.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JSON.stringify()` function like this for indents:

```
const data = JSON.stringify(req.body.detail, null, 4);
```

What I think most people don't know is that `JSON.stringify()` accepts three parameters: first one is the JSON data, second is a function, and third is a number based on how many spaces you want the data to be indented by. Here's the MDN documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: I didn't read the question carefully enough... but it might work

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't escape data on insert into a DB.  You should *filter* data on INSERT (to check it is valid), and *escape* data on SELECT.  It is only when you select the data that the app (or future apps) know where the data will be used.  Some apps won't want escaped data.